# What do this called in PHP

Tags: php, oop, laravel, fluent-interface, method-chaining

In [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) a code like the following may be found:

```
return View::make('hello')->with('name', $name);
```

What I know is that:

- `View` is a class
- `make` is one method of the class `View`
- `'hello'` is a parameter passed to the method `make`

What I don't know is: `with` does it a method of method?! does it a PHP keyword? or does it something defined (if it is, what is its definition?) in the `make` method?

Comment: Looks like a method of the view object to me

Comment: `make` return something with `with` method (I think make returns new View)

Comment: @JohnConde If it is a method, so is there what called method of method in object oriented programming?

Comment: @JohnConde According to the [wiki pedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) Fluent interface is differ than Method Chaining, so Does this scenario is Fluent interface or Method Chaining?

Comment: This actually is both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class View() {
  protected $name;
  public function __construct($name){$this->name = $name;}
  public function with($s, $p){return $this;}
  public static function make($name){
    return new self($name);
  }
}
```

`make` - static method of a class
`with` - method of View object

Look at `View::make('hello')->with('name', $name);` as at followed:

```
$view = View::make('hello');
$view->with('name', $name);
```

`return $this`in with method allows us to followed:

```
View::make('hello')->with('name1', $name1)
                   ->with('name2', $name2)
                   ->with('name3', $name3);
```

This pattern named **chaining**

Answer (score 3):

This is [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). The `with` is just a function of the `View` class too. Chainable class functions return a refference to the class itself, so you can call other methods in the same line. So instead of creating a variable for the class instance and calling each function in a new line you can do this:

```
View::make('view')
    ->with('id', $id)
    ->with('title', $title)
    ->with('name', $name);
```

Without method chaining it would be like this:

```
$view = View::make('view');
$view->with('id', $id);
$view->with('title', $title);
$view->with('name', $name);
```

Also when you do `View::make` you actually call the `make` function of the `View` class without instantiation of the class, so you don't have to do it like this:

```
$view = new View();
$view->make('view');
```

However you still end up with a class instantiation because `make()` creates one, but our goal is to do things easy. We want to create a view with the least amount of *readable* code by throwing away obvious lines that just increasing noise in code but we had to write them due to the nature of PHP. This philosophy makes Laravel so beautifull.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) the with method is used for ViewComposers, bounding the variables passed in the with method to the view for being displayed